# How can I remove HTML elements with JqLite or javascript

Tags: javascript, jqlite

how can I remove the following text 'search:' with JqLite or original javascript?

```
<label>
search:<input type="text">
<label>
```

update

---

I didn't explain the question very clearly. All the HTML elements are created by angular directive I can only manipulate DOM with JQLITE or JS maybe. And also attributes of input may change so I can't replace all the child nodes of label with a new input

Comment: Get a reference to the *label* element. Remove all its child text nodes. What have you tried? This isn't a code writing service: you attempt something, if you have issues, ask about them and answers may be forthcoming.

Comment: @SatejS—perhaps, but also most of [*these*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_JavaScript_libraries). Maybe the OP wants jqlite (hence the tag).

Comment: @SatejS it seems no difference here, html() and text(). but can't figure out a way to delete text node only

Answer (score 1):

Please try this

```
<html>

<body onload="remove()">
    <label>
        search:
        <input type="text" id="search">
    </label>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript">
function remove() {
    document.getElementById('search').remove();
}
</script>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
label.innerHtml='<input type="text">'
```

where label is the query wrapper around that label tag

Comment: But that involves destroying the original input and hardcoding its replacement. What if the input already had a value, or event handlers?

Comment: thanks for your answer! but the attributes of input element are dynamic, are there any other ways to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Here's what you need to do.Given that your HTML is like this:

```
<label>
search:<input type="text">
<label>
```

You need to first get a hold of the label.You do this with

```
$("label")
```

Considering you want to manipulate the text inside, you get $("label").innerHTML.Let's put this in a variable.

```
x=$("label").innerHTML;
```

Then, we use the replace string function to replace the value of "search:" with a blank space.

```
y=x.replace("search:","");
```

We finally push back this value of y to the inner HTML by

```
$("label").innerHTML=y
```

You can shorten this into much fewer steps, but I separated them for ease of understanding.

Comment: how do u select the text node? like `$(lable).content().filter()` ?

Comment: @VincentFu, you could select the span and do `str.parentElement`.This is for the label node. For the input element, `str.nextElementSibling`

Comment: sorry a little bit confused... there is no span at the beginning, in this case we need to select text node "search" first, then use wrap() to create the span?

Comment: @VincentFu, please check the answer.

Comment: thanks @SatejS, this will select and replace all the child nodes of label, including text node and input

Comment: @VincentFu, not really, it only replaces instances of the child where there is "search"